# LÖVE viewport like Libgdx

Tags: viewport, screen-resolution, love2d

I wonder if LÖVE framework has the same feature like Libgdx's viewport, because this feature were really great when I used Libgdx and I wonder if there's anything similar to do in LÖVE.

About viewports: https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Viewports

Comment: Why don't you explain what "Libgdx's viewport" actually is? After that, maybe then we can say whether Love2D has it or not.

Comment: I added the wiki about the viewports. Basically it's a way to make all entities to have the same scale in any screen resolution. On libgdx you define a virtual dimension (width, height) and then you can change your image/sprite/etc its position and size relative to the virtual size of your screen without scaling all your entities manually.

Answer (score 1):

If, by viewport, you mean using normalised coordinates (resolution-independant), then **yes**, LÖVE can do that.
Although it's not available by default in the framework itself, there's always a possibility to add your own features.

You could make a Viewport system using LÖVE's [canvases](https://love2d.org/wiki/Canvas).

Start by creating a canvas with fixed dimensions,
then make your game using percentages of these dimensions instead of regular pixel positioning.

For example, `player.x = 80` (left side of the screen) becomes `player.x = canvas:getWidth()*.1`

Once you've drawn everything into your virtual window -that is- the canvas, you can scale it and render your game to fit any window resolution.

I suggest that you take a look at [this](https://github.com/Ulydev/push) library that handles all the scaling stuff for you,  once you provide your game's virtual dimensions.

Comment: Interesting, I'll use this library and see if it works for me.

Comment: Doesn't work because show this: error in line 72 - attempt to call method 'clear' (a nil value)

Comment: It's not updated for LÖVE 0.10.0, in the meantime you'll have to use 0.9.2
I'll fix this as soon as possible, it's just an issue of replacing canvas:clear() with the new love.graphics.clear() API.